# Generating Metrics in Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition

Tags: cuda, nsight

Here is a window from the Nvidia Nsight visual Studio edition.[image]

I am trying to analyze my CUDA code, but I use the Nvidia Nsight Eclipse Edition. Can someone please tell me how do I get such information in the Eclipse edition? I searched and searched, but could not find any way. This question may appear to be very naive, but it has got me really frustrated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can get these metrics details by NVIDIA Visual Profiler directly by collect metrics. Also the visual profiler can be triggered also from Nsight Eclipse Editon by setting Profile configurations.